# Run AfterUpdate after a control is updated by combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a table called `Product Master Data` which contains 785 records.

I have a form based on this table called `Production`. The first text control on this form is called `Protean Resource` and is an identifier that corresponds to individual records.

I have this control set up as a combo box where, once the resource number is selected, the rest of the text controls on the form automatically update to display the accurate information for the selected record.

One of these controls that is automatically updated is called `Quality Format`.

`Quality Format` can be populated with either:

- `SG Industrial`
- `LG Industrial`
- `SG Retail Carton`
- `LG Retail Carton`

With each of these values corresponding to separate forms.

I am trying to set the `AfterUpdate` event for `Quality Format` so that once the control is autopopulated the corresponding form will automatically open.

```vb
Private Sub QualityFormat_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me.QualityFormat
        Case "QualityFormat= SG Industrial"
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="SGIndustrial"
        Case "QualityFormat= LG Industrial"
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="LGIndustrial"
        Case "QualityFormat= SG Retail Carton"
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="SGRetailCarton"
        Case "QualityFormat= LG Retail Carton"
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="LGRetailCarton"
    End Select
End Sub
```

I'm not getting any error messages, but nothing is happening once `Quality Format` is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not receiving any error messages nor seeing any actions, I would suspect that none of the `case` statements are being validated in your `select case` expression.

I see that you are prefixing each of the `case` statements with `QualityFormat =` which is not required and if not equal to the values returned by your combobox control, would cause the validation to fail.

I suspect the following will therefore operate as expected:

```vb
Private Sub QualityFormat_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me.QualityFormat
        Case "SG Industrial"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "SGIndustrial"
        Case "LG Industrial"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "LGIndustrial"
        Case "SG Retail Carton"
             DoCmd.OpenForm "SGRetailCarton"
        Case "LG Retail Carton"
             DoCmd.OpenForm "LGRetailCarton"
    End Select
End Sub
```

If removing the superfluous prefix does ***not*** solve the issue, the next thing to check would be the actual value being returned by `Me.QualityFormat` - depending on the bound column of the combobox, this may be returning an ID rather than the description that you are expecting.

You can check this by adding a `Debug.Print` to the start of your code so that you may verify the value returned by this control when changing its value, and perhaps also add a default `case` so that you can verify that no prior `case` statements are being validated.

---

It is worth adding that, if you have a form for *every* available option, then due to your naming convention, your code could be reduced to:

```vb
Private Sub QualityFormat_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(Me.QualityFormat) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm Replace(Me.QualityFormat, " ", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful